# Where to find open source code of android Espresso library

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to find the open source code for android Espresso library but couldn't. The [AOSP branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/refs/heads/master) here seems to suggest that the **Espresso source code is removed**. And the [specific commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/a693520e12c4a00813e3dc3b4ad2ca2edc9e8f38) says **Espresso has been open sourced via code.google.com**. But I don't know where to find the official open source code for the library.

Would be great if anyone can point me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/android/android-test

And more specifically for Espresso: https://github.com/android/android-test/tree/master/espresso